# How to Add dynamic control instead of static control?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

I have a collection with fields cityname, statename and countryname and I bind that collection to my wpf form. I want to display the cityname in a Textbox, the statename in a combobox and the countryname in a combobox. All the textboxes and comboboxes should come dynamically. How can I do this job?

Any one suggest me how to design this form dynamically in wpf using MVVM I am trying to do this code but not get result properly. Either I get everything as textbox or combobox, but what i need is textbox and combobox as specified.

```
<Border Margin="3.5">
    <Grid>
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="125" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" MinWidth="100" />
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <TextBlock x:Name="tbFieldTag" Cursor="Hand" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="10,0,0,0" Text="{Binding Path=CardField.FieldTag}" />
            <TextBox Margin="10,0,0,0" x:Name="txtFieldData" Grid.Column="1" MaxLength="{Binding Path=CardField.MaximumLength}"  Text="{Binding Path=CardField.FieldData, Mode=TwoWay}"  />
            <!--<ComboBox  Margin="10,0,0,0" x:Name="comboFieldData" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=CardField.FieldTag}"/>-->
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

Comment: take a look at http://arcanecode.com/2007/09/07/adding-wpf-controls-progrrammatically/

Comment: I think the question is about to add controls dynamically on binding of SQL database to the form. For e.g. if SQL Column is DateTime then corresponding DateTimePicker should appear in form. A text box for string/integer and Combobox for an observable collection of strings.

Comment: yes this is the task amd i want to achieve it using datatemplate

Comment: Thats just a simple for each column add control loop in code isn't it?

Comment: @CodingBarfield: pls give me the any example?

Answer (score 0):

The key to your problem are `DataTemplates`. These allow you to bind your view to a collection of custom objects.

You should have a ViewModel that is exposing an `ObservableCollection<TLocation>` where `TLocation` is a class that is exposing public properties Cityname, Statename and Countryname.

In your View you need to show a `ContentControl`, say a ListBox, having it's `ItemSource` property bound to the `ObservableCollection`.

Then you set the DataTemplate for the Listbox to something like:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=CityName}" />
        <ComboBox Text="{Binding Path=StateName}" />
        <ComboBox Text="{Binding Path=CountryName}" />
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

---

Another approach is to use a DataGrid. See [this article](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dpatra/combobox-in-datagrid-in-wpf/)