# How to update ListBoxItem [with datacontext]

Tags: wpf, data-binding, datacontext, inotifypropertychanged

I have following class as my data context

```
class s
{
public string name{get;set;}
public string family {get;set;}
public string status{get;set;}
}
```

I have made an style for listBoxItem [added 2 more contentPresenter] to match with my datacontext, i mean each content presenters content is set to "{Binding ?}"-? can be name, family or status-.

I set this datacontext to ListBoxItem, but when i change the datacontext, it won't displayed

```
((s)(item.DataContext)).name="change";
```

but i see that nothing is changed.

i Google it but most of the questions was a bit different with mine.

Regards,
PK DEVELOPER

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to using ObservableCollection, you would also need to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface for your class `s` and also, bind the elements of your WPF window to properties of class `s` using data binding.

Below are the details on how to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695.aspx

and, the [Databnding Overview on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx)

Comment: If this object is in an ObservableCollection it does not need INotify but if it's not then implement the INotify

Comment: @MyKuLLSKI INotifyPropertyChanged must be implemented as ObservableCollection alone does not provide any notifications when any property in the collection is changed. See: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/SLListVsOCollections.aspx

Comment: Um... An ObservableCollection implements INotify. Simple as that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5123537/mvvm-observablecollection-question

Answer (score 2):

Do the following:

1. Set the DataContext of the parent element of the ListBox to an ObservableCollection () SCollection or this
2. Set the ItemSource of the ListBox to {Binding} if you set the DataContext to this then use {Binding SColection}
3. Add items to the ObservableCollection and the ListBox will automatically update
4. Then just modify items in the ObservableCollection and not the ListBox

Comment: I would use an ObservableCollection too :). Make sure INotify property is set and the event gets launched too.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I don't really understand your question? Do you want to have a `Listbox` that shows a List of objects of type `s`? If that is the case, I would go for `DataTemplates` as in my answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8642790/how-to-add-dynamic-control-instead-of-static-control/8901580#8901580).

Or do you have a special situation, which forces you to directly set up a bindung for each ListBoxItem?

Comment: setup binding for each ListBoxItem